# use existing EC2 instance in sagemaker studio

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

Hi i have an EC2 instance i created called "my_ec2". I want to use this instance in Sagemaker studio. I know that Sagemaker studio is running on AWS EC2 instances. Is there a way of using my existing EC2  i created or maybe mirror it to the Sagemaker EC2 instance?

Eventually i want to have a notebook in sagemaker studio which runs on "my_ec2" instance. If thats not possible, is there way to mirror "my_ec2" instance configurations to sagemaker ec2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not in the way you're thinking of...

Like a few other managed services, SageMaker might "run on EC2" in the sense of using the same underlying compute platform and (a subset of) matching instance types - but the instances it creates are fully-managed by the service: You won't see them in your account's EC2 console, and you can't use your existing EC2 instances and SageMaker instances interchangeably.

In general, SageMaker should help you reduce reliance on over-provisioned, long-lived servers by making it easier to spin up compute-intensive tasks on disposable instances and only pay for the time that {training jobs / processing jobs / deployed endpoints / etc} run. Notebook environments like SageMaker Studio reset to base container image each time you stop & start them - with [LCCs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lcc.html) the tool of choice for configuring persistent installs/etc between restarts.

As far as I can imagine you might be asking this question because:

1. You have an EC2 [reserved instance commitment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-reserved-instances.html) that you're hoping to use rather than paying outside that to use SageMaker, or
2. You have content (like files or just installed libraries) that you're hoping to avoid having to migrate

If it's (1), the good news is there are similar [savings plans for SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/ml-pricing/) that I think are actually a bit more flexible in practice (portable across instance types/etc)... But the bad news is I don't think it's possible to port your existing commitment across: Better reach out to AWS Support/Sales to ask just in case?

If you really want to use your EC2 through SageMaker Studio UI, then my best suggestion would probably be to just SSH across (or [SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html)) from your SageMaker notebook into your EC2 instance? That should give you some ability to lean on your provisioned compute/EBS files/whatever you're wanting but via the SMStudio entry point. If I remember correctly the current [SMStudio base image](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-distribution) doesn't include an SSH client out of the box, so you might have to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends openssh-client` first.

Otherwise, I'd say just copy whatever data you still want up out of your EC2 on to S3 - and then just shut it down and start using SMStudio instead? Ideally for cost-optimization you want to be keeping your long-lived Studio 'space' compute instance quite small and using on-demand jobs through the [SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for intensive tasks, rather than provisioning a big 'space' and letting it sit there under-utilized.